# Mongodb selecting all fields and conditional field selection in project stage

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema with 50 fields and I need to select all fields, but, one field I want to select based on some criteria, for that I wrote following code:

```
const _tours = await Tour.aggregate()
        .match({booked: true})
        .project({
            "bookedByTask": {
                $cond: {
                    if: {
                        '$in': ['$bookedByTask.tasks.taskId', req.body.taskIds]
                    },
                    then: "$bookedByTask",
                    else: "$$REMOVE"
                }
            }
        });
```

but the code returns only `_id` and `bookedByTask` fields, I need all other fields as well, and I don't want to include all fields by hand, because it will become maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Instead of `$project` try using the `$addFields` stage in your aggregation.

Comment: Thank you so much, I replaced `$project `with `$addFields` and it worked as expected!